# Ruby arrays and how to print them

Tags: arrays, ruby

There was a one-liner in Ruby I saw on this site and lost track of:

if I need to print the results of some action with integers:

```
print {|e| e = e * e}
```

but how do I let Ruby know e is, say, 1 to 10?

Comment: "10.times do.." Or "1..10.each do" or...

Comment: `1.upto(10) { |e| puts e * e }` would work.

Answer (score 1):

use parenthesis around your range

```
(1..10).map {|ele| ele + 3} // 1 to 10 including the last number
(1...10).map {|ele| ele + 3 } // 1 to 9 excluding the last number
```

Comment: "map" works but is explicitly different than "each".

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want to do, but here's an input

```
(1..10).to_a
```

This gives you an array of numbers from 1 to 10.